# Laravel async loading from event to .blade.php

Tags: php, laravel-7

I'm doing one project that is about testing portals. and I had something like this in my controller.

```
    $process = new Process(['../app/Http/Controllers/shcheck.py', '-dj', $request->IP]);
    try {
        $process->mustRun();
        while ($process->isRunning()) {
            // waiting for process to finish
        }
        $headers = json_decode($process->getOutput(),true);
        $data= array('title'=> $title,
        'headers'=> $headers);
        return view('pages.index')->with($data);
    } catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
```

but this approach is not scalable, because some my tests can run over minute, so I was googling and found that I can use events and listeners, stack them into queue, and not wait until job is complete. but now. I have problem, how do I pass headders variable to FE after listener finishes its job?

I have this as blade.php file I was appending to view

```
   @if(isset($headers))
    @if(count($headers)>0)
    <div class="no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row shadow-sm position-relative  p-2 row">
    <ul>
      @foreach($headers as  $head=> $head_value)
        <li>{{$head}}</li>
        <ul>
        @foreach($head_value as $he=> $x_value)
          @if(strlen($he)>3)
          <li>{{$he}}: {{$x_value}}</li>
          @endif
          @if(strlen($he)<=3)
          <li>{{$x_value}}</li>
          @endif
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      @endforeach
      </ul>
      </div>
    @endif
   @endif
```

Do I need to somehow include Ajax for this kind of job? or what is the best way to do it.